# Javascript onclick events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to blur my images by clicking on it. I am using javascript on click event for this purpose. But it is not working exactly as I want. My code is given below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


  $(".ww").click(function(){
    $(this).css("opacity","0.2");
  });
});
</script>

<div class="bg">
    <div class="img ww1"><center><img src="img.jpg" /></center></div>
    <div class="canname"><center>GHULAM MUSTAFA</center></div>
    <div class="partyname"><center>JATOI &nbsp;&nbsp; <span style="color:#CCC;">NPP</span></center></div>
</div>

<div class="bg">
    <div class="img ww2"><center><img src="img.jpg" /></center></div>
    <div class="canname"><center>GHULAM MUSTAFA</center></div>
    <div class="partyname"><center>JATOI &nbsp;&nbsp; <span style="color:#CCC;">NPP</span></center></div>
</div>
```

I want that when I click first image then its opacity would set. And that when I click second image so the opacity of first image would finish and second image would set.

Comment: `$(".ww")` isn't going to select anything, why not use `$('.img')`

Comment: i m using just ww class not img class in this scenario. Also i m not using ww1 and ww2 class only usinh ww class

Comment: @user2009243: Then maybe post the code your actually using, otherwise you are just confusing us and we waste our (and your) time thinking about non-issues. The code you posted contains `class="img ww1"`... so there is clearly the class `ww1`.

Comment: Note that the `center` tag is deprecated. You should use CSS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others already tried to explain, you have to use a selector which actually selects both elements, since you want to bind the event handler to both of them. `$('.ww')` does not select any element in the code you posted.

Toggling the opacity can be easier done when using a class:

```
.selected {
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Add the class to the clicked element and removed it from the element currently having the class:

```
$(".img").click(function(){
    $('.img.selected').add(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Have a look at this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/aZjP7/). This should give you enough information to apply it to your situation.

Comment: Felix... Thankyou very much.. You are awsome... You are genius a life saver.

Answer (score 1):

Because a selector `.ww` does not match `ww1` and `ww2`.

You can see that with

```
console.log($(".ww").length);
```

Use the common class `img` or add the class `ww`.

Comment: i m using just ww class not img class in this scenario. Also i m not using ww1 and ww2 class only usinh ww class

Comment: **There is no class ww to find!!!** That is why it is not working! Do you not understand that?

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#my').toggle(
                  function(event) {
                    $(event.target).css('opacity',0.4);
                  },
                  function(event) {
                    $(event.target).css('opacity',1.0);
                  }
                );

        });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <body>
        <div id="my">asdf</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1.3.2? Really? Feb 20, 2009 release.